# ошибка с npm при загрузке файлов

Tags: node.js, npm

Когда пытаюсь подкачать какой-либо пакет, то выкидывает ошибку

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-50-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/student/gulp/npm-debug.log
```

еще добавляет файл с логами

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'gulp', '-g' ]
info using npm@3.5.2
info using node@v4.2.6
silly loadCurrentTree Starting
silly install loadCurrentTree
silly install readGlobalPackageData
silly fetchPackageMetaData gulp
silly fetchNamedPackageData gulp
silly mapToRegistry name gulp
silly mapToRegistry using default registry
silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
verbose request no auth needed
info attempt registry request try #1 at 15:38:10
verbose request id 90726dec6439348e
http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO
info attempt registry request try #2 at 15:38:20
http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO
info attempt registry request try #3 at 15:39:20
http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:174:17)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:258:9)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:304:10)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:322:5)
silly fetchPackageMetaData     at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:89:5)
silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for gulp { [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
silly install printInstalled
verbose stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO
verbose stack     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:174:17)
verbose stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:258:9)
verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
verbose stack     at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:304:10)
verbose stack     at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:322:5)
verbose stack     at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:89:5)
verbose cwd /home/student/gulp
error Linux 4.15.0-50-generic
error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "-g"
error node v4.2.6
error npm  v3.5.2
error code ECONNRESET
error network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO
error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
error network and is related to network connectivity.
error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
error network
error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Что во фразе *"related to network connectivity. In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings."* вам не понятно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в linux нужно прописывать

> sudo npm install